# Why does syntax "main.py < input.txt" not working

Tags: python, input, command-line

Using the command line, my program would take a .txt input.

The syntax my prof show to do this is:

`python main.py < input.txt`

but I get the error
[IndexError: list index out of range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIXcb.png)

The code I used to open files:

```
import.sys

if len(sys.argv[1]) <= 0:
        print("Please input a file path")
        exit(-1)

    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input_file:
        # loops to create new "arg" array for every new line
        for line in input_file.readlines():
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: That command line is providing the file contents to your script as its *standard input*, there are no arguments being provided so `sys.argv` doesn't have any elements (other than the one at index 0 that gives the name used to invoke the program).

Answer (score 1):

`python main.py < input.txt` will pipe the contents of "input.txt" to stdin on the Python process, you can read this piped content via `sys.stdin`

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Omit the `<` to pass it as an argument.

```
python main.py input.txt
```

main.py:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv[1]) <= 0:
    print("Please input a file path")
    exit(-1)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as input_file:
    for line in input_file.readlines():
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you have only passed one argument to your main.py which is the "input.txt" so change `sys.argv[1]` to `sys.argv[0]`